# logic for checking a Boolean of an object

Tags: vb.net

I have a hashset (of posdata), pos data containing a boolean and a label containing the hashkey. I need to draw up a condtion where it will check that if a boolean for two or three different records does not equal to false. And if the condition is true i want to set the boolean of the two or three records to false. Here is an attempt,

```
 ElseIf (position.strLabel = "b2" And position.blnAvail <> False) And (position.strLabel = "b1" And position.blnAvail <> False) And (position.strLabel = "e1" And position.blnAvail <> False) Then

                                position.blnAvail = False ' trying to set the boolean to false
                                pos = position.strX & " " & position.strY
                                'position.blnAvail = False
                                count += 1
                                Bavailable = False'breaks out of the loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your code with extension

```
<Extension()> _ 
Function IsAnyOf(ByVal s As String, ByVal ParamArray names As String()) As Boolean
   Return names.Any(x => x.Equals(s))
End Function
```

Then your code could be rewritten as

```
If position.blnAvail <> False And not position.strLabel.IsAnyOf("b2", "b1", "e1") then
......
```

Note, I'm translating from C# on the fly, so it may be syntactically incorrect somewhere

Comment: ah so this will check whether or not all three boolean for each hashcode is false. how then would this go about setting all to false?

Comment: No this will check if your `position.strLabel` contains any of the strings required to enter the if condition thus simplyfing the condition. For `position.blnAvail` you test always for False.